# Need a solution to implement xmpp add friends in group chat and sending message to them in once in ios

Tags: xcode, xmpp

I'm having difficulties to add friends, sending invitations and also in group chat like sending one message for all using xmpp. i know that I need to use XEP-0045. But I am not succeeded. Can anybody tell me how to do it.

1. Send friend request for one to one chat.
2. send invitation to join chat room.
3. send message to chat room's friends.

if somebody has sample code that would be great..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show what you have so far?

Comment: I've done login, get friends, one to one chat , chat history, send attachment. Now i need to implement group chat and friend invitation for group chat...

Comment: Please help me to start a chat room using xmpp

Comment: Have you implemented roster functionality? What xmpp server are you using?

Comment: can you help me with sending files.For me socket connect fail delegate is called.@NehaaSaxena.

Comment: XMPPJID *newBuddy = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"buddyname"];
 [xmppRoster addUser:newBuddy withNickname:nil];  To send buddy request over XMPP

Comment: Hi neha, please refer the below question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803896/disconnection-of-xmpp-client-while-sending-big-size-image-video-and-audio/22805397?noredirect=1#22805397

Comment: @nehaa Saxena have you compeleted with file transfer using xmppFramework?

Comment: @NehaaSaxena r u there?

Comment: @NehaaSaxena hello I want your help for file transfer using xmpp framework have you did this? if yes, then help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for #3 : send message to chat room's friends.

```
-(void) sendGroupMessage:(NSString *) groupJID Message:(NSString *)msg{

    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.%@",groupJID,SERVER_URL]];

    XMPPRoom *muc = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:xmppRoomStorage jid:roomJID
                                            dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [muc   activate:xmppStream];

    [muc   addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [muc   sendMessageWithBody:msg];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Point 2: Send invitation to join chat room.

You can send invitation to others when you get the response in following delegate (xmppRoomDidCreate):

```
- (void)xmppRoomDidCreate:(XMPPRoom *)xmppRoom
{
    NSLog(@"xmppRoomDidCreate");
    [xmppRoom inviteUser:[User JID Here] withMessage:@"Your Message Here"];
    // You can send invitations in loop if you have multiple users to invite
}
```

Point 3: Send message to chat room's friends.
Actually the message is broadcasted in group. Surely shall be delivered to all members in group.

```
- (void) sendMessageInGroup:(NSString *) message withGroupName:(NSString *) groupName
{
    NSString * qualifiedGroupName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", [groupName lowercaseString], SERVER_NAME];

    //      self.xmppRoomDetails consists of your muc rooms' objects i.i XMPPRoom
    for (int i = 0; i < self.xmppRoomDetails.count; i++)
    {

        XMPPRoom * room = [self.xmppRoomDetails objectAtIndex:i];
        XMPPJID * myRoomJID = room.myRoomJID;
        NSString * roomName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", [myRoomJID.user lowercaseString], SERVER_NAME];

        if ([qualifiedGroupName rangeOfString:roomName].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            XMPPRoom * sendMessageWithRoom = [self.xmppRoomDetails objectAtIndex:i];
            [sendMessageWithRoom sendMessage:message];
        }

     }
 }
```