# How to send image in chat usig xmpp framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmpp, chat

Hi I am making an app based on the chatting I can send chat messages, but if i add image attachment to the chat message, its not working.here is my message code

```
if (![[messageStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] && imgURL==nil) {
      return;
}
NSString *MyString;
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm,yyyy/MM/dd"];
MyString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *myJID=[defaults valueForKey:@"userNameJID"];

    if ([imgURL length]==0) {
       chatMessageToSendAndPutInDB=[messageStr mutableCopy];
       chatMessageToSendAndPutInDB=[[chatMessageToSendAndPutInDB stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""] mutableCopy];
    }else
    {

       receivedDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          chatMessageToSendAndPutInDB=[receivedDataString mutableCopy];
        chatMessageToSendAndPutInDB=[[chatMessageToSendAndPutInDB stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""] mutableCopy];

    }
    [DBObject open];
[DBObject insertInTable:@"chatTable" withUserId:myJID withFriendID:[[ASNGlobalClass shareManager] chatToUserJID] withMessage:chatMessageToSendAndPutInDB withTimeDate:MyString withLeftOrRight:0];

 NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[DBObject closeDatabase];
[self fetchDataFromDatabase];
   if([messageStr length] > 0 ) {

  [body setStringValue:messageStr];
   }else if ([imgURL length]>0){
             [body setStringValue:receivedDataString];
   }    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];

[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:chatWithUser];
 NSXMLElement *chatStatus=[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"composing" xmlns:UIApplicationStateActive];
[message addChild:chatStatus];
[message addChild:body];
[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement:message];
```

I am using xmpp framework and openfire server. and i don't know how to send images.please help me and i am using sqlite for storing and fetching
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://kashiftriffort.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/xmpp-how-to-send-message-with-image-using-xmpp-in-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

attachment element is used to send image in XMPP.
you can use following function:

```
-(void)sendMessage:(NSString *)strText img:(UIImage *)SendImage{
NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
[body setStringValue:strText];

NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:userId];
[message addChild:body];

if (SendImage) {
    NSData *dataF = UIImagePNGRepresentation(SendImage);
    NSString *imgStr=[dataF base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    NSXMLElement *ImgAttachement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"attachement"];
    [ImgAttachement setStringValue:imgStr];
    [message addChild:ImgAttachement];
}

[self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
[self.view endEditing:YES];}
```

Comment: Hi Ankit i tried your code but image not sent to chat and i choose image from pikerview it is assiging to SendImage but not attched to messege i don't know where i miss.

Comment: Is it throwing some kind of error. if not, then Try with some dummy image which is present in your project and then try. And on receiving end check the body of message in - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Saini but it is not showing any error and image also and i implement some code check it once if you know any thing please let me know and i am using sqlite for storing the data

Comment: @Ankit Saini: I tried your code..and it work for small size images...but when I tried to send 1MB size image it not worked.any suggestions?

Comment: @bittu, you can compress the image before attachment using UIImageJPGRepresentation and then send

Comment: I also tried that, but no success. here is the code which i am using               if (sendImage != nil) {
                let dataF = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sendImage,1.0)
                let imgStr = dataF?.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                let imageAttachement = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "attachment", stringValue: imgStr!) as! DDXMLElement
                messageElement.addChild(imageAttachement)
            }

Comment: @bittu, UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sendImage,1.0)  should be like UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sendImage,0.5), 1.0 means you want the original size.
please up-vote if it is helpful.

Comment: ok....but i have 1 issue..what if I want to  send video?what should I do in above code?

Comment: Please check this link if it is helpful. [xmpp media](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803896/disconnection-of-xmpp-client-while-sending-big-size-image-video-and-audio)

Comment: I already visited that link..but I am not getting how to implement it in code.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3.0

```
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)
    let imageStr = data?.base64EncodedString()

    let body = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "body") as! DDXMLElement
    let messageID = XMPPManager.sharedInstance.xmppStream?.generateUUID()
    let imageAttachement = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "attachment", stringValue: imageStr!) as! DDXMLElement

    let message = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "message") as! DDXMLElement
    message.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "chat")
    message.addAttribute(withName: "id", stringValue: messageID!)
    message.addAttribute(withName: "to", stringValue: buddyJID.full())
    message.addChild(body)
    message.addChild(imageAttachement)

    XMPPManager.sharedInstance.xmppStream?.send(message)
```

But If xml size is large, server will return size error.
So First upload image to file server and then send url by xmpp protocol

Answer (score 0):

For sending a small image to friend you can use the below function, but for sending a large image/video/audio file, it is recommended to share large files  via streams "out of band" and use XMPP as signaling protocol - you should just send http:// or rtp:// link, and your buddy's client will download it, or start playing audio/video from given stream.

You can use `XEP-0066`: Out Of Band Data - simple extension, where you just attach URL to standard  element.

**Sending Image**

```
//Send Image to friend with message.
-(void)sendMessageWithImage:(NSString *)strText img:(UIImage *)SendImage {

    //Message string with image.
    NSString *messageStr = strText;

    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
    [body setStringValue:messageStr];

    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type"stringValue:@"chat"];

    //set "to" string value to friend jid
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to"stringValue:@"rohit@192.168.0.1"];
    [message addChild:body];

    NSData *dataPic =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(SendImage);

    NSXMLElement *photo = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"PHOTO"];
    NSXMLElement *binval = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"BINVAL"];
    [photo addChild:binval];

    //convert image to base64String
    NSString *base64String = [dataPic base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    [binval setStringValue:base64String];
    [message addChild:photo];

    [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement:message];

}
```

**at Receiver end**

`XMPPStream` Delegate Methode.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message {

    [self MessageReceive:message];

}

#pragma mark - Receive New Message Methode.
-(void)MessageReceive:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
    //Get friend XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject object
    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message from]
                                                             xmppStream:xmppStream
                                                   managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

    //Get Message if friend send with image.
    NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];

    //Get Display name of friend.
    NSString *displayName = [user jidStr];

    //Check friend send image or only text message
    if ([message elementForName:@"PHOTO"]) {

        //Get Image from base64String
        NSString *photoHash = [[message elementForName:@"PHOTO"] stringValue];
        NSData* data = [photoHash dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSData *nsdataDecoded = [data initWithBase64EncodedData:data options:0];

        //Here you can get image.
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:nsdataDecoded];

    } else {

        //Here you can get friend text message
        NSString *message = body;
    }
}
```