# how to send image in somessaging xmpp framework

Tags: ios, sqlite, chat, xmppframework

I am developing a chat app message sending is fine but unable to send the images in xmpp framework and i am using somessaging class for chat screen so ca any body tell me how to send the images in xmpp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send image in chat usig xmpp framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946115/how-to-send-image-in-chat-usig-xmpp-framework)

Comment: There are lots of question related to this please search it on Google. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=send+images+using+xmpp+ios&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Wk03VsHXOs7ToAT87I7QAg#q=send+images+++using+xmpp+ios . and to impliment image sending in somessaging you have to develop your own logic . First, understand somessaging how works. then send and receive photo using it else use your own custom collectionview or tableview with custom cell.

Comment: Thanks for replay i tried my own logic but not working well when i send image then all cell items are hidden i don't know how to implement do you have any sample code for this please i am struck here

Answer (score -1):

For sending image in Xmpp first you need to convert image to string format and while receiving image you need to convert string format to image format.

**Sending Image**

```
 NSData *imageObj = UIImagePNGRepresentation(YourImage);
 NSString *imageString = [imageObj base64EncodedString];
imageString = [imageString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```

**Receiving Image**

```
  NSString* _imageData =[SentImageString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%2B" withString:@"+"];
NSData *dataObj = [NSData dataFromBase64String:_imageData];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataObj];
```

Comment: it's generic answer. You are supposed to convert image to data while sending over web service or XMPP or anything. please consider answering about how to this with 'XMPP'.