# How to receive notification in XMPP Group Chat in IOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

My Apologies if this question was asked before. I have created group chat i am able to send the messages but I don't receive any notification when other person sends a message to me. To get the message i have leave & rejoin the room to get all messages.

Comment: Have implemented push notification for group chat?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the room's delegate to take care of the receiving room message?

try to set the room delegate :

`[#XMPPRoom# addDelegate:]`

Comment: Yes, I have added Delegate

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create a MUC Room;   [Click Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377907/ios-xmppframework-creating-a-group-chatroom-issue/26177223#26177223)

And this how you invite participants in MUC and send messages to them:   [Click Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336755/need-a-solution-to-implement-xmpp-add-friends-in-group-chat-and-sending-message/26177182#26177182)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in background mode then you will surely get notification. But for this you have to create Local Notification. You have to create Local Notification in below method.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.alertAction = @"OK";
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        localNotification.alertBody = xmppmessage;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];

}
```

If you are not online while another user send you message, so at this stage you have to use PushNotification.

Comment: What if the user is offline and the message sent to group. How the offline user gets the notification?