# iOS - XMPPFramework - creating a group chatroom - Issue

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am developing a chat app in iOS. In XMPP server (Ejabberd in this case,I have enabled MUC ). I have registered a user and now trying to create a chatroom using an registered user. Also in MUC, the Host setting is defined properly

```
{host, "conference.@HOST@"}
```

But I am not able to create a chatroom

The code I am using is below

```
XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage *rosterstorage = [[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc] init]; 
NSString *jid =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UserName"]; 
jid=[jid stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@localhost" withString:@""]; 
jid=[jid stringByAppendingString:@"@conference.localhost"]; 
NSLog(@"jid is here :%@",jid); 
// timok@conference.localhost 

XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:rosterstorage jid:[XMPPJID     jidWithString:jid] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()]; 
[xmppRoom activate:[appdel xmppStream]]; 

[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm]; 

[xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil]; 
[xmppRoom addDelegate:appdel delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()]; 
[xmppRoom inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"motik@localhost"] withMessage:@"Hi join room"];
```

In the above code timok and motik are registered users. When I attempt to create a room, I am getting the below error

```
2014-04-29 18:25:27:996 konnectlinks[16112:5e03] SEND: <message to="timok@conference.localhost"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user"><invite to="motik@localhost"><reason>Hi join room</reason></invite></x></message> 
2014-04-29 18:25:28:280 konnectlinks[16112:5a43] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="localhost" id="99D56CEF-3DEA-4D3D-B186-D3B1C28FEE8F" type="error"><error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq> 
2014-04-29 18:25:28:280 konnectlinks[16112:a0b] paduaAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ: 
2014-04-29 18:25:28:564 konnectlinks[16112:5a43] RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="localhost" id="D9F3BE9A-F4EB-4361-8F1A-C51FD5880AD8" type="error"><error code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq> 
2014-04-29 18:25:28:564 konnectlinks[16112:a0b] paduaAppDelegate: xmppStream:didReceiveIQ: 
2014-04-29 18:25:28.564 konnectlinks[16112:a0b] didNotConfigure
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue will be very helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791022/trouble-creating-xmpp-muc-room-code-503-service-unavailable ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) createOrJoinEventGroupChat:(NSString *) groupJID{

     XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.%@",groupJID,SERVER_URL]];     

     XMPPRoom *muc = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:xmppRoomStorage jid:roomJID dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

     [muc   activate:xmppStream];

     [muc   addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

     [muc   joinRoomUsingNickname:@"User Name" history:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 - (void)createOrJoinRoomWithRoomName:(NSString *)roomName nickName:(NSString *)nickName 
        {
            if(roomName && nickName)
            {
                _xmppRoomStorage = [XMPPRoomHybridStorage sharedInstance];
                XMPPJID *roomJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@.%@",roomName,@"conference",self.hostName]];
                _xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_xmppRoomStorage jid:roomJid];
                [_xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
                [_xmppRoom activate:_xmppStream];
                NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
                [history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:MAX_ROOM_HISTORY];
                [_xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:nickName history:history];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"room creation arguments missing");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To Create MUC Room

```
- (void)createChatRoom:(NSString *) newRoomName
{
    NSString * xmppRoomJID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", newRoomName, CONFERENCE_ROOM_SERVER_NAME];
    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:xmppRoomJID];

    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];

    xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc]
                initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage
                jid:roomJID
                dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom activate:[self xmppStream]];
    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:[Your Nickname or Number Here] history:nil];
    [xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];

}
```